# Handling Chrome "www.xyz.com wants to: Download multiple files" Alert / Popup in automation - Robot Framework & SeleniumLibrary

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm having an issue attempting to download 3 files off of a single button click when automating a test (Using Robot Framework with SeleniumLibrary, writing code in VSCode). Chrome shows a popup, saying "*insert domain* wants to: Download Multiple Files" then lets you choose Allow or Decline. I need to allow for all 3 files to download successfully.

Chrome Popup Image:

[image: Chrome Popup Image]

I've been trying to use Press Key or Handle Alert keywords provided by the SeleniumLibrary in Robot Framework but this has not worked.

I've also attempted to launch Chrome with various argument to override this popup, with no avail. There was also an attempt to see how to change the preferences in a file that chromedriver will launch with, and hard code in the URL, but I couldn't find the file chromedriver uses.

I know the SeleniumLibrary allows you to execute JavaScript, however do not have any experience with JavaScript, and would not know where to begin.

I'm unsure how to handle this alert, since it I've tried to read up on as many questions about this online. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For me following ${prefs} option worked with Robot Framework and used browser was Google Chrome 89.0.4389.72 (Official Build) (64-bit):

```
    ${prefs} =    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${download_directory}    plugins.always_open_pdf_externally=${TRUE}
...    **profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads=${1}**   download.prompt_for_download=False
```

So, you can use: profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads=${1}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that may be a notification.  You can turn these off, but not sure if that's what you want here.  To turn off notifications in ChromeDriver use something like this (java):

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  

             prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);           
             options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);  
     driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: This might work, I will implement this with my tests and let you know how it goes. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Too late for the answer, but anyone else if searching for Robotframework way.
Add this to your Chrome prefs..

```
${CHROMEPREFS}             Create Dictionary  profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads=${2}
Open Browser    ${URL}      ${BROWSER}      options=add_experimental_option("prefs", ${CHROMEPREFS})
```